# How to properly implement an addObject() function in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, design-patterns, implementation

I am new to this website.
I am sorry if this has been asked but I just can't find any questions / solutions that answer my question since I think this is a pretty specific question.
So I have been learning how to create a game engine with SFML in C++ and I have a question regarding how to implement an addObject() function that, upon being called, creates an object that gets added to a vector of objects in a class in an optimized manner.
Here is my attempt:
Object.h

```
class Object{
private:
    string m_Type;
    string m_Action;
    int m_PositionX;
    int m_PositionY;

public:
    Object(string type, string action, int positionX, int positionY){
        m_Type = type;
        m_Action = action;
        m_PositionX = positionX;
        m_PositionY = positionY;
    }

};
```

ListOfObjects.h (where the addObject() function is)

```
class ListOfObjects{
private:
    vector<unique_ptr<Object>> m_Objects;

public:
    void addObject(string type, string action, int positionX, int positionY){
        m_Objects.push_back(move(make_unique<Object>(type, action, positionX, positionY)));
    }
};
```

Now this works fine but I figured there might be better ways to implement this.
The reason why I have this thought is that when I tried to change the constructor of the `Object` class, say I want to add one more parameter (e.g. `Object(std::string m_Type, std::string m_Action, int PositionX, int PositionY, int Scale);`), now I would need to also update the parameters of the `addObject(...)` function as well as well as the following line of code where I called the `make_unique` function.
That is a lot of work (or not, really I don't know, I'm still a beginner lol). So I figured can I make the `addObject(...)` take a temporary object instead of a list of parameters to match the constructor of the `Object` class itself?
ListOfObjects.h

```
class ListOfObjects{
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> m_Objects;

public:
    void addObject(Object object){
        m_Objects.push_back(move(make_unique<Object>(object)));
    }
};
```

Now, whenever I need to change the constructor of the `Object` class, I don't need to update the addObject(...) function.
But now, I need to add `Object` like this:

```
int main(){
    addObject(Object("name", "action", 100, 50));
    //and then a lot of random errors associated with memory and pointer stuff :(
    return 0;
}
```

I actually tried to implement this but there is just a lot of errors and my small brain just can't comprehend what went wrong. I don't know if passing a temporary object into a function is an expensive operation. Should I pass in a reference of the temporary object like this? `addObject(Object& object)`

So the main question is:
Is there a better way to implement this function to add an object such that adding more parameters to the constructor of `Object` does not require me to update the `addObject(...)` function?

Any help would be much appreciated! (And sorry for such a long question :<)

Comment: If you have a class with only a single member variable and functions that mimic what you can already do to that member variable, then you probably just want an instance of that member variable. i.e., you want a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> list_of_objects;` in your `main`.

Comment: oh i see what you mean, but this is just a simplification of my game engine code, its actually a vector of buttons in a UI Panel class, But thanks for the suggestion tho, real appreciate it!